# Цикл и поток

Tags: c#

Есть поток, в нём цикл . В comeBox выводиться почему то 5 раз цифра 6. Что я делаю не так?

```
private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                System.Threading.Thread myThread = new System.Threading.Thread(get_lists);
                myThread.Start();
        }
        void get_lists()
        {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
        BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => comboBox1.Items.Add(i)));
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делайте так:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    int closed_i = i;
    BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => comboBox1.Items.Add(closed_i)));
}
```

Проблема в том, что вы делаете closure на *переменную* цикла, а не на её *значение*. А она меняется! Код `comboBox1.Items.Add(i)` начинает выполняться не *немедленно* во время вызова `BeginInvoke`, а через какое-то время, в будущем. В тот момент, когда он начнёт выполняться, цикл скорее всего уже закончится, и переменная `i` примет финальное значение 6.

Классическая [статья Эрика по теме](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful).

Comment: Да уж. С веб-программирования переходить на прикладное трудно =(

Comment: @MadKeks: в javascript'е [та же фигня](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/06/05/10531181.aspx) :-(

Comment: Мне повезло и с циклами в JS не приходилось работать. Только в  PHP

Comment: @MadKeks: Удачи вам в изучении C#. Мой совет — сразу бросайте устаревшие WinForms и садитесь на WPF.

Comment: Времени у меня много, успею. Спасибо вам за помощь.